# Simplifying and putting in values in an equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider this equation

$$ y(x) =v_0 \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}  \frac {x} { v_0 \frac 1 2} - \frac 1 2  g  \frac {x^2} {v_0^2  \frac 1 4}$$

Now I want to simplify it so I could find the x easier (all of the other values I have) I've gotten rid the v0 in the denominator and numerator.

$$ y =\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \frac {x} {  \frac 1 2} - \frac 1 2   g   \frac {x^2} {v_0^2  \frac 1 4}$$

And I think you should be able to get rid of the $ \frac 1 2$ and the part of the $\frac 1 4 $

So the equation should look like this

$$y(x) =\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}  \frac {x} { \frac 1 2} -  g   \frac {x^2} {v0^2  \frac 1 2}$$

Did I do my simplification wrong? If yes where, and can the expression be simplified more?

Thank you!

Comment: $\displaystyle \text{You don't need to write } y(x) =vo *\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} * \frac {x} { vo *\frac 1 2} -  g  * \frac {x^2} {v0^2 * \frac 1 2};$ $${}$$ you can write
$\displaystyle \text{you can write } y(x) =v_o \cdot \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \cdot \frac {x} { v_o \cdot\frac 1 2} -  g \cdot \frac {x^2} {v_0^2 \cdot \frac 1 2}.$ $${}$$

Comment: Im sorry but where is the diffrence

Comment: @codeisfun Usually $*$ almost never means multiplication in written mathematics. Typically multiplication either does not have a symbol or sometimes ```\cdot``` is used. ```*``` is only used for multiplcation in programming languages like Mathematica, Python etc, and never in written mathematical work, as typically $*$ is used to denote convolution.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you for the info.

Comment: @codeisfun : An asterisk is used for ordinary multiplication only when one is limited to characters on the keyboard. Here we use MathJax. In MathJax and LaTeX and TeX one can write $3\cdot5$ or $3\times5. \qquad$